# How to continue numbering a list from where it stops?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-lists

I'm reading content from some API, and the content may come as either come as "paragraph" or "ordered list".

My list order is always restarting numbering every time it reads a new record. 
Example
1.TEST
1.TEST

My goal is to display the content as follows
1.TEST
2.TEST
even after reading different content in between

```
@foreach (var x in item.copy)
        {
            if (x.type == "o-list-item")
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.text)
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
            else if(x.type== "paragraph")
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.text)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
```

I understand that if the list sequence is interrupted, then it is a new list sequence, and can’t be a continuation of a previous list.
But, I have to make it, and

I tried to custom code myself, by concatenating an integer count=1 and increment when the for loop reads "o-list-item" type of content, but the DisplayFor razor view seems not allowing to concatenate any custom made variables.

```
 @foreach (var x in item.copy)
    {
        if (x.type == "o-list-item")
        {
         int count=1;
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        count + "."+ @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.text)
                        count ++;
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
        else if(x.type== "paragraph")
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.text)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    }
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot of C# and haven't seen this @foreach annotated like this yet. But maybe you could have some method that receives the text, from this method build a string concatenating the counter and the text received. Something like:

```
public List<String> receivesFromApi() {
    return new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  public String iteratesThroughList() {
    int counter = 1;
    for(String data : receivesFromApi()){
      System.out.println(counter+"."+data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ordered List attribute "start" to specify start number.

```
@{int count = 1;}
@foreach (var x in item.copy)
            {
                if (x.type == "o-list-item")
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ol start="@count++">
                            <li>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.text)
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
                else if(x.type== "paragraph")
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.text)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried but no success, still it displays 1. TEST 1.TEST

Comment: Do you see the start attribute in the rendered HTML as "1" for all the lists? I think the count variable is not being incremented for every loop.

Comment: yes, I put break point, and it is always 1, and don't increment

Comment: Solved, I put count++ before the <tr> and just read <ol start=count>